# setText Value Not Showing

Tags: android, android-viewpager

`setText()` Value showing in `LOGCAT` But Not showing in Layout.Strange behavior.Does any guys meet this issue?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

   //set ViewPagerIndicatorView
    this.viewPagerIndicatorView = (ViewPagerIndicatorView) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_indicator_view);
    final Map<String, View> map = new HashMap<String, View>();

    map.put("About", LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_sample_pager_2, null));
    map.put("Locations", LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_sample_pager_1, null));
    map.put("Reviews", LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_sample_pager_0, null));

    this.viewPagerIndicatorView.setupLayout(map);
    LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    layout = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_sample_pager_0, null);
    View linearLayout = layout.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Loading();
}

public void  Loading(){
    String Value="My Name Is";
    Tv1=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.TvBasicInfoFP);
    Tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Tv1.setText(String.valueOf(Value));

    Log.d("TextView",Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply inflating a layout is not enough:

```
layout = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_sample_pager_0, null);
```

It's not shown to you yet.

It must be added to your root view:

```
LinearLayout rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
rootLayout.addView(layout);
```

And in your `activity_my.xml` you have a root layout with an id, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```